# Is it possible to have a struct where the field is an item from an enum? Rust

Tags: design-patterns, rust, syntax

Is it possible to have a generic struct such that the items in the struct are items from an enum? For example:

```
enum AcceptableDataType {
    String(String),
    U8(u8),
}

struct Data<K, V> 
where 
    K: AcceptableDataType,
    V: AcceptableDataType,
{
    map: HashMap<K, V>,
}
```

Or is this something that should be handled by traits? Im just not sure how to approach this situation in the rust way.

Comment: `map: HashMap<AcceptableDataType, AcceptableDataType>`? Please expand more on what your use case is.

Comment: Are you trying to restrict the types that can act as keys and values in your map? If so, using a marker trait would be the way to do that.

Comment: I am trying to restrict the data types. I essentially have a struct acting as a database held in memory and I want to make sure that the data in that struct can be serialized into a familiar format when writing to disk. After looking at the problem and reading the responses here it seems like I should just be reaching for some kind of trait to make sure the data is serializable similar to the serde api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you should implement this with traits, by creating a trait that's implemented on both `String` and `u8`.

```
trait AcceptableDataType {}

impl AcceptableDataType for String {}

impl AcceptableDataType for u8 {}

struct Data<K, V> 
where 
    K: AcceptableDataType,
    V: AcceptableDataType,
{
    map: HashMap<K, V>,
}
```

Do note that in `Data`, you can't just "check" which type it is, you only know that it's an `AcceptableDataType`, which doesn't give you any info.

If you need to get back an enum of both, I'd include a method in the trait to do so, as such:

```rust
enum AcceptableDataTypeEnum {
    String(String),
    U8(u8),
}

trait AcceptableDataType {
    fn into_enum(self) -> AcceptableDataTypeEnum;
}
```

and also implement the function in the impls.

If you don't want any downstream users to be able to add new items to the trait, you can also make it [sealed](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/future-proofing.html#sealed-traits-protect-against-downstream-implementations-c-sealed).

If you have a complicated set of impls, possibly involving generics that overlap, but you just want to use the trait as a "marker", then you can also use the unstable night-only feature `marker-trait-attr`.

Note however, that this prevents you from having methods on the trait, so you can't use the approach above to get back an enum, you'd need specialization for that, which is an incomplete feature.

Answer (score 1):

No. There was an RFC for that, [Types for enum variants](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450), but it was [postponed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450#issuecomment-271042602):

> While we may want to do something along these lines eventually, given [the roadmap](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1774) I think there is more pressing work on the language side, and this RFC has stalled.

The idiomatic way is just to use the payload type (you may need to create a struct for it). Like:

```rust
struct Data<K, V>  {
    map: HashMap<K, V>,
}

Data<String, u8>
```

You may use a trait to be able to construct the enum, e.g.:

```rust
trait Enum<Variant>: Sized {
    fn from_variant(v: Variant) -> Self;
    fn into_variant(self) -> Option<Variant>;
    fn as_variant(&self) -> Option<&Variant>;
    fn as_variant_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Variant>;
}

impl Enum<String> for AcceptableDataType {
    fn from_variant(v: String) -> Self { Self::String(v) }
    fn into_variant(self) -> Option<String> {
        match self {
            Self::String(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
    fn as_variant(&self) -> Option<&String> {
        match self {
            Self::String(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
    fn as_variant_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut String> {
        match self {
            Self::String(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
impl Enum<u8> for AcceptableDataType {
    fn from_variant(v: u8) -> Self { Self::U8(v) }
    fn into_variant(self) -> Option<u8> {
        match self {
            Self::U8(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
    fn as_variant(&self) -> Option<&u8> {
        match self {
            Self::U8(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
    fn as_variant_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut u8> {
        match self {
            Self::U8(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

struct Data<E, K, V>
where
    E: Enum<K>,
    E: Enum<V>,
{
    map: HashMap<K, V>,
}
// etc.
```

Note this trait is not perfect: it doesn't work if two variants have the same payload type. You can refine it to work in that case too, and also create a proc macro to easily derive it.